# Unpermitted Parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a sign up form for my site, and included the following parameters in my users_controller.rb file in order to save the data entered into the corresponding fields to my database. For some reason, when I attempt to submit my created Sign Up form, the console is telling me that firstname and lastname aren't permitted parameters. The error is:

> Unpermitted parameters: firstname, lastname

The sign up is successful, and the other parameters are entered into the database just fine; however firstname and lastname columns remain empty.

**users_controller.rb**

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "You signed up successfully"
    flash[:color] = "valid"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
    flash[:color] = "invalid"
    render "new"
  end
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end


def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
end

end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

    </br> <%= f.text_field :firstname, placeholder: 'First Name' %> 
    </br> <%= f.text_field :lastname, placeholder: 'Last Name' %>
    </br> <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email' %> 
    </br> <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password' %>
    </br> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Confirm Password' %>


    <%= f.submit :Register %>
  <% end %>
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "password"
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password

  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: -> { new_record? || changes["password"] }

end
```

**Incoming Parameters (console)**

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1hHzXu2RZR3G3Zx4PoOeDu3DlU31V5abDH/UmNx+w9hs/gacgRYhFgpe6cm0d7cLaTtZdfROi3oUrw/m5EcTAQ==", "user"=>{"firstname"=>"Milhouse", "lastname"=>"Vanhoutten", "email"=>"milhouse@thesimpsons.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
Unpermitted parameters: firstname, lastname, 
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "milhouse@thesimpsons.com"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$T.iv9b3BjG.t1FJvT7YsVOZf0wNOD2QSFA9lP8RGOiE1h5AaDdB2q"], ["created_at", "2016-01-18 22:12:32.764948"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-18 22:12:32.764948"]]
   (7.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to /users/6
Completed 302 Found in 122ms (ActiveRecord: 8.7ms)
```

Comment: Can you show your User schema (from the schema.rb file) ?

Comment: Show submitted params hash

Comment: @SteveTurczyn See Schema added above.

Comment: @Brittany Can you put in a debugger before `@user = User.new(user_params)` and print out what `params` is? Also the model would be helpful as it is likely the problem lies there.

Comment: @JesseWhitham Added user.rb; see above.

Comment: Actually ignore printing the params can see it in the Incoming Parameters update, just put up the model

Comment: Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails?autoplay=true for using a interactive debugger it is really handy for finding problems

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Are you using any kind of Authentication gem? I.e devise?

Comment: @AntarrByrd Version 4

Comment: @JesseWhitham Something else to note: When I add a user to the database through the terminal, it works just fine. It's only through the form submission that it leaves the two mentioned values out.

Comment: @Brittany I just created a project using your users controller, form and model (With just the first and lastname fields) and everything worked fine. Have you tried bringing down the app and putting it back up again?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parameters may be coming in as

```
{:firstname => 'foo', :lastname => 'baz'}
```

instead of

```
{"user" => {"firstname" => "foo", "lastname" => "baz"}}
```

It can probably be traced back to the form.

Comment: Sorry for the newb response - but why would this happen on those two values and not e.g. the email value? How can I fix this?

Comment: That's actually fair. Can you show the incoming parameters? They should be printed in the rails webserver output.

Comment: See incoming parameters above - and thanks so much, appreciate it.

Comment: np.. although from the code you posted I can't see why it would behave that way.

Comment: I'm so confused as to why this is giving me grief - lol. When I create a user through the terminal, it works just fine?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, but with the update method. Turns out it was caused by an `around_update` callback I was using. I changed the `around_update` callback to `after_update` and the problem was fixed.